# How can i create a Hibernate Session in a @RabbitListener Method?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-amqp

I want to consume messages from a rabbitmq. As part of this process i read an entity from a spring-data repository. When i try to access a lazily initialized field of this entity i get:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Here is my Listener:

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = {
    @QueueBinding(
        value = @Queue(value = EVENT_QUEUE, durable = "true"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = EventConstants.EVENT_EXCHANGE_NAME, type = EventConstants.EVENT_EXCHANGE_TYPE)
})
@Transactional
protected void handleSubscriptionCreated(Subscription subscription) {
  // just sample code
  repository.find(subscription.getId())).getAccount();
}
```

i tried to create a session by enforcing a transaction, but that does not work.

Comment: the issue seems to be related to the fact that you load the entity but you are trying to use some related entity and it is not initialized because it is fetched in a LAZY way; may you post some code of repository and account entity? Or you may do `Hibernate.initialize(repository.find(subscription.getId())).getAccount())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `@Transactional` Annotations on Listener methods only work if the listener Method is public.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-666

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your `@Transactional` for an appropriate `JpaTransactionManager` bean reference.